# Film capacitor identification

Tags: capacitor, components

I tried to repair a device and these two film capacitors were broken. I can read "393K 250V" on one cap but can't recognise the manufacturer logo due to the scratches.

Could you help me identify the manufacturer? Otherwise I guess any cap can work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is an amazing thing

https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/530780/7a11ce85afa1498543bf984153733752/pdf-markingandorderingcodesystem.pdf

Anyhow, if you don't wanna read that

The one you can read is "39 * 10^3 pf" or 39,000pf  or 39nF,   250V

NOTE:  THe OTHER one has "630V" partially visible.  i.e. THAT'S A HIGHER VOLTAGE CAP.  Don't drop a 250V in there.

Since it's about the same size, but much higher voltage, it is likely to be a lower capacitance than the 39nF part

The "k" is a tolerance

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is a useful document!